# Troubleshooting with rowMeans() - 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

Tags: r

I have a dataframe where the first column is a timestamp, and the remaining 16 columns are numeric values. I'd like to create 4 new columns (or a new df) where each column is the mean of 4 of the data-columns, meaned by row.

Trying to do this one mean at a time I use:

```
 nightdata2 <- rowMeans(c(Nightdata$X3356D, Nightdata$X3356C, Nightdata$X3356B, Nightdata$X3356A) )
```

I am trying to concatenate the four columns that are related and average the rows, and having probelms.

with a resulting error: "'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions"

Is there something easy I am overlooking?

Comment: Are you confusing `c()` with `cbind()` or `rbind()`?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this which passed 4 columns at a time to rowMeans:

```
sapply( seq(2,17 by=4), function(start) rowMeans(Nightdata[,x:(x+3)])
```

Untested in the absence of a reproducible example. May want to use `lapply` to prevent the simplification of `sapply` and then `do.call(cbind, ...)` to align them.